# iOS5/xCode Setting up an array with a json file for use later on

Tags: json, ios5, nsmutablearray

I have the following code that I run at viewDidLoad:

```
  NSString *json_list = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mylist" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *theList   =   [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: json_list];
NSInputStream *listStream = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:theList];
[listStream open];

if (showStream) {
    NSError *parseError = nil;
    id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:listStream options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];        
    if ([jsonObject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
        for (NSDictionary *firstItem in [jsonObject objectForKey:@"list"]) {
            NSLog(@"Title: %@", [firstItem objectForKey:@"title"]);
        }
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"Failed to open stream.");
}
```

All is OK but I would like to store this information into say an array so that I can use later within this view, but I have had a go at soem various array methods mutable etc but seem to have got stuck at this part of it:

Ideally instead of the NSLog bit:

```
   NSLog(@"Title: %@", [firstItem objectForKey:@"title"]);
```

this is where I would probably add it to an array, but how can I do this to use later on?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
if ([jsonObject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {

    self.titleArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *firstItem in [jsonObject objectForKey:@"list"]) {
        NSString *title = [firstItem objectForKey:@"title"];
        [self.titleArray addObject:title];
    }
}
```

Where titleArray is a property declared in your .h file.

Comment: Greta thanks you, just been racking my brain all day.  Now to take the local json and have it connect online and then do the same thing :-)